# PDO and MySQL query, same query with sqllite PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL, ODBC etcetera?

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, mysqli, pdo

For a long time I've been using *MySQL* and I'm using more *MySQLi* nowadays.

I'm thinking about switching to *PDO* or get more out of *MySQLi*. I don't know what will be better and how our future looks like, unfortunately [image: :)]

I've seen some examples online about PDO and have seen that CREATE, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE query/functions are not the same.

**example i need** (depending on the query) **to use :**

```
$db->exec();
$db->execute();
$db->prepare();
```

Cause there are different ways to do the same it will make me personally confused and not easy to make a function or class of them.

My question here is if i can use the same query's with different databases or do i have to write my code depending on what database i use. I found this code online.. They are *(almost but)* not the same.

**MySQL**

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE user (
id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL, 
email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (id))";

$mysql->exec($sql);
```

**SQLLite**

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE books(
id int,
title varchar(255),
author varchar(255))";

$sqllite->exec($sql);
```

Do i miss something? Am i seeing this wrong? Can i write the same code for different databases?  UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE, CREATE, DROP

Everybody writes positive about PDO... I am always seeing things different [image: :)] Maybe someone can share his opinion or awnser my question to start with, before to jump into something new.  **Thanks**

Comment: PDO can connect to different databases. Mysqli can only connect to mysql. The queries you write will have to match the syntax for the DB they are going to. e.g. `select top 5 user from users` will work on mssql but will break mysql and vice versa with `select user from users limit 5`

Comment: This one might convince you: [Usability problems of mysqli compared to PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mysqli_comparison)